# Import-SPWeb loses user information

Tags: 2010, import

I am using `Import-SPWeb` to import a site into a new site collection.

The import works as expected, but after import it shows me as creator/modifier on all the documents in the site. Also all permissions to site/library are lost.

I know that if users no longer exist then it defaults to the user running the command but this is not the case. All users still exist in the system.

I am using `Central Administration` to export the site and I have the option `Export full security` checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use PowerShell instead of the central admin backup.

```
Export-SPWeb -identity "http://URL/sites/subsiteToBeExported" -Path "LocationToStoreExport\exportname.cmp" -includeUserSecurity
```

The location for the backup can be local on the server ( best for performance ) or a UNC path where the account that runs the command got read/write permissions.

**IncludeUserSecuirty** make's sure that the all the user permissions are intact and the data for created, modified, created by and modified by are preserved.

Also take a look at the **IncludeVersions** parameter if you are using versions on the subsite.

[Export-SPWeb](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx)

Comment: Glad to hear. When the UI gives up, PowerShell works most of the time. :)

Answer (score -2):

You can import the exported backup via the administration console using `Import-SPWeb` with `IncludeUserSecurity` option.